# Is there a simple way to modify this code?

Tags: c

I'm just under 2 weeks into learning to code, and I built a working grade book program. Is there a SIMPLE way to modify this code from **Just accepting and reproducing entered grades**, to **using a custom structure to allow for grades (0-100) and ID numbers for each student to be entered**?

When the grades are printed out at the end, I would like them to be sorted by ID.

Here's my current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_GRADE_COUNT 200

int main() {

    int *grade;
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    char continueResponse;

    grade = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_GRADE_COUNT);

    if(grade == 0) {
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("Welcome to Gradebooker!\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_GRADE_COUNT; i++) {
          printf("Enter a grade(0-100): ");
          scanf("%d", grade + i);
          count++;
          printf("Continue?(Y/N): ");
          scanf(" %c", &continueResponse);

          if(continueResponse != 'Y' && continueResponse != 'y'){
             printf("\n>> End of Grade Input <<\n\n");
             break;
          }
    }

    printf("Current List of Grades: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {

       printf("\t%5d\n", *(grade + i));
    }
    printf("\n\Thank you for using Gradebooker!\n");

    free(grade);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a general overview of the `struct` data type, which is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. SO questions are typically related to a specific issue in code (something like "Why does this code snippet produce an unexpected output"). Somewhere like reddit.com/r/c_programming might be a better place to post this sort of broad question.

Comment: Now your grade is `int` type. Create new struct type, `struct grade { int grade; int student_id; };` and make your grade array be `struct grade *grades = malloc(sizeof(sturct grade) * MAX_GRADE_COUNT);`.

Comment: @Barmar As this question ask for a new feature (sort by id), it's off topic on Code Review.

Comment: @Barmar I added it to Code Review, and it's immediately being downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @svangordon I'm really so new at this, that I'm unsure how to really be more specific. I'll try that reddit. Thanks.

Comment: @zeta I removed it from Code Review. I've done a decent bit of studying on Custom Structures, and how to implement them, I'm just too raw to comprehend how to plug it into an existing program. Like, I have these 20 Legos in my hand, and I know what they do and why, but I'm not good enough with them yet, to make anything other than clunky trash. :(

Comment: It sounds like you need a mentor. Unfortunately neither Code Review nor Stack Overflow provide mentoring, they only provide reviews (CR) or answers (SO). I suggest you to split your new feature ("read all names, ids and grades, and sort them according to x,y,z") into several, e.g. "Write a program that reads student IDs, names and grades, and then prints them in the same order they were given". When you manage that task, you can post your result on Code Review to get some feedback. Alternatively, you can try to sort an array. Or: before you build a Lego Minas Tirith, build a small house :).

Comment: @zeta I built a tree fort. Now, I'm trying to hammer the "No girls allowed" sign to it, and my nails are weird and mysterious. :p

Comment: A quick search, online, for a 'bubble sort' or a 'insertion sort' or read the MAN page for the function: `qsort()`